# A term for "combining of related phrases"

Tags: single-word-requests, linguistics

Sometimes two related phrases are reached for simultaneously. I recently heard a newscaster combine "standpoint" and "point of view," so that his sentence began "from a football standpoint of view..." is there a name for this phenomenon?

*Portmanteau* is close but it usually applied to single words.

Comment: The newscaster has been watching too much "Wheel of Fortune"! Sounds like he's hung-up on the puzzle called "before and after":  " FOOTBALL STANDPOINT/ OF VIEW." (Don't overthink this one!)

Comment: @rhetorician - The game show *Jeopardy!* uses that same terminology – "before and after."

Comment: A "blend word" ? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_word

Comment: This is simply a form of tautology.

Answer (score 2):

*I'll stick my neck out on a limb...*

I think this is a good example of a **[malaphor](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/Malaphor.htm)**.